# Excel Count True for Search in a Range of values for each match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How can I count the True returns in a count for each search for a substring that returns True?

I can return 1 result from a cell if I supply a range however it fails.

So works for one cell.

```
=COUNT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Data!S12)))
```

Where B2 is a word I am searching and Data!S12 is a cell in the range I want to go over, Data!S:S.

Trying to create this as an array formula so to **not use VBA**

How can I do this?

Comment: make it an array formula but define your S maximum row so you are not doing the ENTIRE row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUM(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(O2,S:S))))
```

Make sure you press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when you are done entering your formula instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  You will know you have done it right when you see { } around the formula in the formula bar.  You cannot add the { } manually.

---

Another option for you is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(O2,S:S))))
```

Take heed, you should not do the above with the entire column if you can avoid it.  you should limit your range to your data or you can wind up bogging yourself down.

---

You could really simplify it by using some wild cards in your search  Say the word you are looking for is "boy", you could use the following

```
=COUNTIF(S:S,"*boy*")
```

or if you want to make your search word cell dependent you can use:

```
=COUNTIF(S:S,"*"&O2&"*")
```

Proof of concept with later two formulas

[image: Proof of concept with countif]

You can read more about [COUNTIF here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)

Comment: Have you ever used subtotal to count only visible cells? =COUNTIF(SUBTOTAL(103,Data!$S:$S),"*"&Sheet2!B2&"*"))

Comment: I have not used it but subtotal formula is a special beast.  it can ignore itself if it occurs within the range it is summing.  and if I recall correctly there are other options with it and you can do more than just sum with subtotal.  I would say its the precursor to the aggregate function

Comment: I could be wrong but it looks like your leading quote is missing the wild card...or maybe your removed the wild card on purpose

Comment: I am gathering by your follow up question in the comments that you are summing over column S and you have hidden rows in S that you do not want counted?  If so you should technically post that as a separate question. which I am sure many here are already working on answers for 8)

Comment: A think that was just a TYPO in SO. Will make a helper column with subtotal which should make it easier to manage

Comment: if you are making your helper column, use something like `=--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(O2,S:S)))` for the helper column.  it will give you a list of 0 for false and 1 for true.  Then use your subtotal on that column to sum non hidden cells.